# What does "/1/" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, date

I was reading a piece of code on the internet.
I saw this line in the javascript code.
What is "/1/" and "/0/" used for in the following code statements??

```
    var firstDate = new Date(String(monthNum) + "/1/" + String(yearNum));
    var lastDate = new Date(String(monthNum + 1) + "/0/" + String(yearNum));
```

Comment: Did you try to print `String(monthNum) + "/1/" + String(yearNum)`?

Comment: It's just a string literal used as a building block for a bigger string here

Comment: it's a string, they are concatenating a date, the output should be something like `new Date("month number/1/ year number")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"/1/"` and `"/0/"` are nothing except string literals.

You are concatenating these two strings with your `month` and `year` string (formed by calling `String()`, although I think they are not needed) to construct a particular date string.

Comment: so I changed ur rep to 10k... congrats :)

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: So it seems. Thank you very much!